# SQL Server aliasing with column calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm making this calculation in my SQL statement:

`CD_WELLBORE_FORMATION.prognosed_md + {fn IFNULL(CD_DATUM.datum_elevation, 0)}`

How do I alias this calculation to say, "MD"? I've tried different placements of the AS keyword, but I keep getting syntax errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
        prognosed_md + {fn IFNULL(datum_elevation, 0)} AS MD
FROM (SELECT 1 AS prognosed_md, 2 AS datum_elevation) T
```

works fine for me. Why not just use `COALESCE` though instead of the ODBC sequence? `COALESCE` is standard SQL...

Comment: Rookie mistake... I had a syntax error further along my query that was compounding to make me think the aliasing was wrong. Thanks though for the `COALESCE` tip though. Definitely learned something new.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this:

```
(
 CD_WELLBORE_FORMATION.prognosed_md 
 + {fn IFNULL(CD_DATUM.datum_elevation, 0)}
) as MD
```

<s>I assume that `{ fn IFNULL ...}` is just something you put here as an example. That's obviously invalid SQL</s>

Comment: That's an ODBC escape sequence

Comment: @MartinSmith Thank you. First time I see something like that. I thought it was invalid.